# ExecuteNonQuery uses significantly more download than upload bandwidth?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

For context, I have the following code in .NET which connects to my SQL DB, adds parameters to the command, and then executes a stored procedure on the server. The following code only runs when a difference in values is detected so the stored procedure queries the last entry in the DB and then creates a new INSERT statement with either the values that were sent from this program or the last values in the DB (if they are the same, to save bandwidth). My bandwidth usage by this program is, for example, over 5 minutes about 38 KB download and only 1.5 KB upload. I don't understand why there is so much traffic being downloaded if `ExecuteNonQuery` should only return the number of rows affected.

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert_into_modbus",connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); ++i)
    {
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        sb2.Append("@");
        sb2.Append(list[i]);
        String pN = sb2.ToString();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(pN, (int)values[i]);
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: have you tried this with different stored procedures?  e.g. a sort of null procedure that only performs a wait?  I'm imagining that the download is some sort of polling that may always happen.

Comment: How do you measure the download and upload numbers? Are you sure that this figures are due to your sp and not something else?

Comment: @Steve I believe it is due to the SP because I was implementing this before without a SP by simply sending the INSERT statement as the command and the bandwidth was basically all upload.